# Permissions don't appear to be working correctly on a new Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions

I have a new server which is joined to our domain.  When I try to save a text file in a folder I am getting access denied.

- I am logged in with a domain admin account
- I have checked that 'domain admins' is a member of the machine's 'Administrators' group
- 'Administrators' have full control of the folder in question.
- I have checked the account I'm logged in as on the 'effective permissions' page and it has full control.

Yet I get access denied when trying to save a text file into the folder. Any ideas?

**Edit:**  I just checked my domain functional level, and it is 2000.  Could this be the cause?

Comment: Is UAC enabled? In which directory are you trying to save this file? Are you launching the text editor using "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: It's php.ini in c:\Program Files (x86)\php\v5.4\   But same applies to any folder I haven't created myself.  UAC is enabled but that never got in the way before, and it is supposed to prompt me,  not just completely deny access.

Comment: I can save the file if I open it from a notepad or text editor opened as admin,  but this is incovenient as I can't right click on the file in explorer and open it from there.   I have to open the text editor first and then open the file to do it this way.   I should be able to do anything as I am logged in as a domain administrator.

Comment: UAC won't prompt you from within every app (as you now see) -- if you think you should be able to do "anything" when logged in as an administrator, then you'd need to set UAC to auto-elevate (some people call this "disabling"). Be aware that in 2012+ disabling UAC will prevent many applications from functioning.

Comment: I disabled UAC and it let me save,  So I guess I will have to put up with having to save the 'long way round'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no denies in permissions as they will override allow. Test other folders/disks to narrow down where all you are being prevented. Try testing with a user of a separate 'allowed' group. If this is through a network share, verify both the share and file system permissions. Log out and log back in...

Comment: I checked for denies,  there are none.   Also I think that would have shown up in the effective permissions as a loss of full control and write and so on.

Comment: Hmm,  can't seem to edit my comment.  I was going to add that I'll check the other things.  I am unable to add or edit files in any folder on the machine except folders that I create.  This is strange because I've created many new servers in recent months and not had this problem.